# Accelerator physics text

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

Physicist here, looking for a suggestion for a very comprehensive, very detailed textbook on accelerator physics---particularly with a focus on cyclotrons/synchocyclotrons/AVF-cyclotrons. My work is medical-adjacent, and proton accelerators seem to be described by repetition rates, treatment pulse lengths, bunch lengths, current, etc. But I'm having difficulty finding a reference that gets into the nitty gritty. What's the difference between a pulse and a bunch? Why do cyclotron references keep (maddeningly!) mentioning RF systems when they don't seem to be driven by cavities like a synchotron is? How far apart in time are bunches and pulses? Why can't I find a single reference on the entire internet that talks about time- and beam-structure in detail?

I have no difficulty with Jackson/Zangwill-level references (which are preferred, in fact), so please don't hold back. Definitely not looking for a link to a CERN outreach page, y'know?

Comment: You could try the books that the CERN document server comes up when requesting accelerators. There are 200 of them , many e-books, and you could see if one answers your questions http://cdsweb.cern.ch/search?ln=en&cc=Books&sc=1&p=accelerators&action_search=Search&op1=a&m1=a&p1=&f1=

Comment: You might look into the US Particle Accelerator School and attend.